# Deferred links not working as iPad now behaves as desktop in iOS 13

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

We have noticed that iPads with iOS 13 are no longer retaining the data for deferred deeplinks, via Branch.io.

We believe this is due to the user-agent details being sent as desktop (even though its an iPad). We can resolve this issue by disabling the "Request Desktop Websites", however as this is now a default setting, is there another work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Branchster here -

Yes, since iPads are treated as Desktop devices, the Branch Links redirect to the fallback URL(your website URL). To update this and redirect the links to AppStore instead you can go to the Configuration section of your Branch Dashboard and add the redirection for iPad Redirects.
[image: Branch Dashboard Advance Mobile Redirects]

You can add the store download link here so that deferred deep linking works as expected.

Comment: How can you handle this if you are passing parameters in the link? We've tried redirecting them to the store via fallbackUrl and its show the Mac (desktop) store listing

Comment: Can you share the link?